# sending mail using Fluent Email in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-core, smtp

I am trying to send email with attachments using Fluent Email here is my code

```
var emailtosend = Email
          .From("info@gorollo.com")
          .To(email)
          .Subject(string.Format("Confirm Your Account"))
          .UsingTemplate(@"C:\Emailer\TransactionTemplate.htm",true)
          .Replace("##Username##", name)
          .Server("smtp.example.org")
          .WithSSL(true)
          .WithCredentials("info@gorollo.com", "password")
          .Send();
```

i saw various examples but not able to find that what code is working right for it can anyone please help me to solve this problem
when i applied this code then it is showing error on line
and how can i add port number to this code

```
  .Replace("##Username##", name)
```

please see that attached image

[image]

Comment: There's no `Replace` in an `Email` object - What are you trying to replace exactly?

Comment: please look at this link
http://dkdevelopment.net/2010/09/03/easy-email-templates-in-net-with-fluentemail/

Comment: i am trying to replace name from template from ##contactname

Comment: Have you read th first line from the page you linked?  **Update: The “Replace” method of templating in Fluent Email has itself been replaced by a Razor Engine Template. See Luke’s Post here about it.** Take a look: http://lukencode.com/2011/04/30/fluent-email-now-supporting-razor-syntax-for-templates/.

Comment: This article is very old. FluentEmail now uses Razor templates and there is no need to replace variables there the way you do in your example.